# outer <div> height 0px

Tags: html, css

```
<div class='outer'> 
  <div class='inner'>
    <p> Some text ... </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

The outer div is shown to have height zero. even css property of `.outer { border: 1px solid black; }` is displayed as a single line on top of the page.

how do you make sure the outer div actually encapsulates the enclosed inner divs in html?

Comment: Don't float or absolutely position its children.

Comment: Can you please give an example for your problem, because it's work's in jsfiddle. please see - http://jsfiddle.net/tcncT/

Comment: ok, but see http://jsfiddle.net/tcncT/1/ . Please make the jsfiddle for your problem, it's help to getting real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did one of two things.

1. You floated the `.inner` left or right and did not clear the float and did not set `overflow: {auto|hidden}`
2. You absolutely positioned `.inner` and there is no other content to create some width for `.outer`

Your code is behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try give it `height: auto;`
If this isn't fixing your problem, please upload the code to jsfiddle. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding css overflow: auto property to the outer div usually helps.